# How to define the return variables in AWS Amplify API call

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am trying to code the following GraphQL query in React

```js
{
    getAllGenericDB (filter: {
    SK: {
      beginsWith: "Seat"
    }
      }) {
      items{
      SK
      SeatStatus
    }
    }
}
```

I dont want the PK to be returned, i need only the SK and SeatStatus how do i specify the below in React? Below is what i have achieved so far.

```js
getPosts = async() => {
        const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getAllGenericDb, {filter: { SK: {beginsWith: "Seat"} }
             }))
        console.log("All Posts:", JSON.stringify(result.data.getAllGenericDB))
    }
```

Below is the colsole output

```js
All Posts: {"items":[{"PK":"TABLES#TheTableName","SK":"Seat#1","SeatStatus":"Occupied"},{"PK":"TABLES#TheTableName","SK":"Seat#4","SeatStatus":"Occupied"},{"PK":"TABLES#TheTableName","SK":"Seat#6","SeatStatus":"Occupied"}],"nextToken":null}
```